# VB Script not calling Bat file through command prompt

Tags: vbscript

I have a vb script file which calls the bat file and these files are in UNC Path.
am executing the vb script using command prompt, it is executing but it is not calling the bat file.
this is the code which i have written to call the bat file.
sUsername is the username of the admin
fullpath is the absolute path of the vb script file
setupfile is the bat file name : edx.bat

objShell.run ("runas.exe /noprofile /user:" & sUsername &" "&""""& fullpath &"\" & setupFile & """")

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Did you manage to get it working?

Answer (score 0):

Is it not asking for a password when you use runas with /user?